# Is CImg compatible with Emscripten

Tags: c++, linker, emscripten, cimg

I have written a program in c++, but need to turn it to javascript to be run on an iPad. The only issue is that my program uses CImg. This is the compile command

```
em++ -std=c++11 -Wall  -L./lib -lX11 -ljpeg -lpng -I./include -I./include/include  main.cpp  obj/object1.o obj/object2.o -o bin/executable.js
```

`./include` has my program header files and `./include/include` has all the files that were located in `/opt/X11/include` which are needed to run CImg. and I get the following error:

```
warning: unresolved symbol: XUnlockDisplay
warning: unresolved symbol: XMoveWindow
warning: unresolved symbol: png_read_info
warning: unresolved symbol: XWindowEvent
warning: unresolved symbol: XFreeColormap
warning: unresolved symbol: XAllocClassHint
warning: unresolved symbol: XCreatePixmapCursor
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_sig_bytes
warning: unresolved symbol: XGetWindowAttributes
warning: unresolved symbol: pthread_testcancel
warning: unresolved symbol: XSync
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_start_decompress
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_CreateDecompress
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_stdio_src
warning: unresolved symbol: XQueryKeymap
warning: unresolved symbol: png_create_write_struct
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_destroy
warning: unresolved symbol: png_read_end
warning: unresolved symbol: XCreateImage
warning: unresolved symbol: png_write_image
warning: unresolved symbol: XSetWindowColormap
warning: unresolved symbol: pthread_cancel
warning: unresolved symbol: XGrabKeyboard
warning: unresolved symbol: png_read_image
warning: unresolved symbol: XSetWMProtocols
warning: unresolved symbol: png_write_end
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_gray_to_rgb
warning: unresolved symbol: XCheckTypedEvent
warning: unresolved symbol: png_init_io
warning: unresolved symbol: XFree
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_filler
warning: unresolved symbol: XUnmapWindow
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_longjmp_fn
warning: unresolved symbol: XCreateSimpleWindow
warning: unresolved symbol: XMapRaised
warning: unresolved symbol: XCloseDisplay
warning: unresolved symbol: XLockDisplay
warning: unresolved symbol: png_create_info_struct
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_IHDR
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_write_scanlines
warning: unresolved symbol: XSelectInput
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_finish_compress
warning: unresolved symbol: XPutImage
warning: unresolved symbol: XCheckWindowEvent
warning: unresolved symbol: XUndefineCursor
warning: unresolved symbol: XVisualIDFromVisual
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_set_quality
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_CreateCompress
warning: unresolved symbol: XFreePixmap
warning: unresolved symbol: XCreateBitmapFromData
warning: unresolved symbol: pthread_create
warning: unresolved symbol: XStoreColors
warning: unresolved symbol: XInitThreads
warning: unresolved symbol: XLookupString
warning: unresolved symbol: png_get_valid
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_read_header
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_stdio_dest
warning: unresolved symbol: XSetInputFocus
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_std_error
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_destroy_decompress
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_palette_to_rgb
warning: unresolved symbol: png_create_read_struct
warning: unresolved symbol: pthread_setcanceltype
warning: unresolved symbol: png_read_update_info
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_set_defaults
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_read_scanlines
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_start_compress
warning: unresolved symbol: png_destroy_read_struct
warning: unresolved symbol: XResizeWindow
warning: unresolved symbol: png_get_IHDR
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_destroy_compress
warning: unresolved symbol: XCheckMaskEvent
warning: unresolved symbol: XCreateColormap
warning: unresolved symbol: XGetVisualInfo
warning: unresolved symbol: pthread_setcancelstate
warning: unresolved symbol: XDestroyWindow
warning: unresolved symbol: png_write_info
warning: unresolved symbol: XDefineCursor
warning: unresolved symbol: XUngrabKeyboard
warning: unresolved symbol: XSetClassHint
warning: unresolved symbol: png_set_tRNS_to_alpha
warning: unresolved symbol: jpeg_finish_decompress
warning: unresolved symbol: png_sig_cmp
warning: unresolved symbol: png_destroy_write_struct
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZTVSt9exception
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with linking the libraries. But I don't know if it is even possible to work with CImg while converting through Emscripten.

Answer (score 0):

Any portable C or C++ codebase should work. But you do need to port all dependencies. Looks like the app uses Xlib and libpng, based on those warnings. You might need to port the X stuff to something emscripten already supports, like SDL. For png, there are a few ports around (or you can compile it yourself), e.g. https://github.com/hachque-Emscripten/libpng-1.2.49

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the X11 features of CImg (basically, if you don't want to display an image into a CImgDisplay window), then you can disable it by defining the macro `cimg_display=0` while compiling your CImg-based code.